# All about datives, or: What's that funny "le" or "me" doing in there?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-indirectos, preguntas-canónicas

> This is a [canonical question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) / Esta es una [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)

This is a canonical question and answer about dative uses of **le, les, me, nos, se, te** and **os** that often confuse and confound the Spanish learner.

**Dar** (*to give*) is a common example of a verb that takes *two* objects, for instance

> **Te** lo doy en un momento. ~ *I'll give it to you in a moment.*

When we see the indirect object **te** in a phrase like this, we know it's the *recipient* of the action.  But what about other ways of using the indirect object, such as

> ¿**Me** saludas a la familia? ~ *Say hi to your family for me, okay?*
>
> Las plantas siempre se **me** mueren. ~ *Plants always die on me.*
>
> Láva**te** las manos, por favor. ~ *Wash your hands, please.*
>
> Vamos a tomar**nos** una cerveza. ~ *Let's go have a beer.*

What's going on with these other uses of object pronouns?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that question. Great work Pablo! Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Whatever the answer, we don't say dative in English. That's for Latin.

Answer (score 32):

The [dative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_case) is commonly known as the [grammatical case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case) of [indirect objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)#Types_of_objects) (the secondary object of [ditransitive verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb) like *dar*), and it is marked in Spanish by the use of special pronouns (*me, te, le, nos, os, les, se*) and its position in the sentence.

The indirect object is an [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)) of the verb, i.e. it is part of its core syntax. For example, *me* in *«¿Me lo das, por favor?»* is a dative pronoun and functions as the required indirect object of the verb *dar*. This is easy enough; students of Spanish learn this kind of thing together with the verbs (in this case, that *dar* needs three arguments: a subject, a direct object and an indirect object).

In this answer I will not be talking about that. Rather, my focus will be on the dative when used as an [adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)).

Explanation and examples come from the *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española* (NGLE). The *Diccionario de la Lengua Española* (DLE) also mentions this briefly in its entry for *[dativo](https://dle.rae.es/dativo)*.

### Dative of interest

The **dative of interest** (NGLE 35.7b) marks a person or thing that is benefitted, harmed, or generally affected by the action or process. It corresponds to the *dativus commodi* or *dativus incommodi* of classical Latin. It can sometimes be difficult to distinguish from the garden variety indirect object. One indication that you're looking at a dative of interest is that it can often be replaced with *para* or *por* (the dative of interest appears in boldface):

- *Salúde**me** a la familia.* = "Say hello to the family (for me).", equivalent to *Salude a la familia por mí.*
- ***Nos** trabajó todo el día.* = "He worked (for us) the whole day.", also *Trabajó para nosotros todo el día.*
- *Ella **le** cocinó un plato especial.* = "She cooked a special dish (for him)."

Such a substitution will be more or less natural, depending on the register, dialect and exact expression.

### Ethical dative

The **ethical dative** is a dative that shows a certain interest, concern or involvement on the part of the referent. It sometimes overlaps with the sympathetic dative (see below). For example (based on NGLE 35.7r, with the dative pronoun in bold):

- *El bebé no **me** duerme.* "The baby doesn't sleep."
- *Las plantas siempre se **te** mueren.* "Plants always die."
- *Se **les** puso nerviosa.* "She got nervous."

You'll notice that in these three examples, I've refrained from translating the ethical dative pronoun.  But this little pronoun is actually essential to get the meaning of the sentence. In the first example, the pronoun *me* refers to the first person singular and the implication is (1) that the baby is the speaker's child, and (2) that it pains the parent that the baby is not sleeping. The latter is the mark of the ethical dative; the former also makes it a sympathetic dative.  In English this could be expressed as "The baby won't sleep for me."

In the second example, *te* indicates that plants always die under *your* care; in English this could be translated as "Plants always die on you (when you try to care for them)."

In the third example, someone is getting nervous and this is clearly a concern for some specific people (who are referred to by the pronoun *les* -- the 3rd person plural). Here, the dative suggests that the person who got nervous is under the care or watch of others who have an active interest in her.  Perhaps, by getting nervous, there's some concern that she might have let them down. In English this phrase could be expressed as "She got nervous on them."

In each case it would be possible to remove the dative pronoun and keep the basic English translations I've provided.  But valuable information would be lost.

### Sympathetic dative

The **sympathetic dative** (also known as **possessive dative**) is widely used in constructions with body parts or other [inalienable possessions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inalienable_possession).  It marks an attribution which can be possessive or inclusive (NGLE 35.1e, 35.7f-q).  The dative indicates *who* owns the body part or possession; and the body part or thing possessed must appear with a definite article. For example:

- ***Me** lavo las manos.* "I wash my hands."
- *Se **le** cae el pantalón.* "His pants are falling down."
- *¿**Te** duele la cabeza?* "Does your head hurt?" (Is your head causing you pain?)

This is a structure that often confuses Spanish learners, since in English and many other languages, body parts and inalienable possessions (such as articles of clothing) are indicated by simple possessive pronouns ("My pencil broke"), whereas in Spanish, we prefer (or sometimes need) the sympathetic dative to accomplish the same thing (*«Se me quebró el lápiz»*).

The sympathetic dative works also for simple possession, association and family relationships:

- *Se **le** inundó la casa.* "The (=his/her) house got flooded."
- *Se **nos** casó María.* "(Our) María got married."
- ***Te** quedó muy bien el artículo.* "The (=your) article turned out well."

In each case there's an implication of association (the house belongs to the third person implied by the pronoun, María is part of the speakers' family, and the article was written by the person being spoken to).

### Aspectual dative

The **aspectual dative** (NGLE 35.7v) is used for several kinds of emphasis. One particular feature of it is that it always agrees with the subject of the sentence. It therefore looks like a reflexive verb or a regular pronominal verb, but it's not truly reflexive and it differs from the pronominal verbs in that the pronoun is not compulsory. The aspectual dative is often found with verbs that indicate consumption of food and drink, like *beber* and *comer*, but also of figurative consumption (of news, of reading):

- *Ayer **me** comí una pizza.* "Yesterday I ate a pizza."
- *Vamos a tomar**nos** una cerveza.* "Let's go have a beer."
- ***Se** leyó los diarios mientras desayunaba.* "He read the newspapers while he had breakfast."

The implication that the dative pronoun adds is that the "consumption" was complete or that it had a definite ending (cf. perfective aspect). The emphasis is often achieved by adding words like *todo/a(s)* or *completo/a(s)*. In each of the above examples, the aspectual dative indicates that the action (eating a pizza, drinking a beer, reading the newspapers) was finished as expected. There are limits to the use of this dative, related to the semantics of the action it indicates; you cannot say, for example, **«Ayer me comí pizza»*, because *pizza* as a mass noun is not bounded and therefore its consumption cannot be marked as "finished."

In some cases the aspectual dative changes the meaning of the verb, which can then be considered to be a pronominal version of the basic form. For example (NGLE 35.7y):

- *saber algo* = "to know sth.", but *saberse algo* = "to know sth. by heart"
- *creer algo* = "to believe sth.", but *creerse algo* = "to take sth. as true on good faith"
- *llevar la plata* = "to transport the money", but *llevarse la plata* = "to take the money away, to run away with the money"

Note how in these examples the verb with the aspectual dative implies a "perfect" (finished) action: *saberse algo* implies "to have memorized sth."; *creerse algo* implies "to have come to accept sth. as true"; *llevarse la plata* implies "to have taken the money without obvious intention of returning it."

### Addendum: a joke that uses confusion of two different datives

This is just something I couldn't resist to add. It's a joke that illustrates the ambiguity of some uses of the dative. The author I don't really know; the one who comments on it is [Elena Álvarez Mellado](https://twitter.com/lirondos/status/1086005907035705348), a computational linguist.

[image: – Alexa, pídeme una pizza. – ¿Me das una pizza?]

The joke is a command directed at the home personal assistant Alexa, followed by Alexa's reply. It reads:

> –Alexa, pídeme una pizza.
> –¿Me das una pizza?

A literal translation of this into English would not be successful. Here is a non-literal translation:

> –Alexa, order me a pizza.
> –Can I have a pizza? [Give me a pizza, please, will you?]

The confusion stems from the fact that the dative, used with the verb *pedir*, admits two meanings: a regular indirect object or a dative of interest (i.e. showing someone for whose benefit an action is intended). Therefore the imperative *pídeme una pizza* may mean "order me a pizza; order a pizza **for me**", which is a dative of interest and of course the intended meaning; but it could also mean "ask me for a pizza; ask for a pizza **from me**." Context and common sense should make this clear, but machines don't have common sense and IAs are still notoriously bad at reading context.

Comment: Hair falls *out*.  But I took out the hair because there was a hard C in two consecutive examples.

Comment: Excellent, thorough explanation...thank you for this!

Comment: @pablodf76 - Now in the light of day I can't clearly remember why I switched the hair for the pants -- but the pants example looks pretty good to me.  See what you think.

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks for the edits. I've re-edited a couple bits, especially near the beginning. I tend to be terse when writing about complex subjects where there's a reference elsewhere, forgetting that not everybody will be able to find that reference, and as you implied, an extra-long text is preferrable to an overly terse technical text.

Comment: Fantástico ejemplo el de la pizza. También lo vi en Twitter, qué bueno que lo añadas a la respuesta.

Comment: El bebé no me duerme. "The baby doesn't sleep." is really: I can't get the baby to [go to] sleep. Las plantas siempre se te mueren. "Plants always die **on me**.", as you said.  Se les puso nerviosa. "She got nervous." I disagree. Isn't that: "[ella] Se puso nerviosa"? Isn't Se les puso nerviosa: She became nervous while with them.

Comment: @pablodf76 - As always, please roll back anything that doesn't feel right of what I just edited.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree about the baby.  I was thinking about editing that part just now, in fact.  "Dormir al bebé" is indeed "get the baby to sleep." In the end I decided to leave it alone because parents of young babies often complain about both, that the baby won't go to sleep *now* and that the baby doesn't seem to be sleeping well, or enough, *in general*. // Regarding the getting nervous example, yes, "she became nervous while with them" might be accurate, depending on the exact situation. // Tip: you can format text in comments by typing an asterisk before and after a phrase to italicize it.

Comment: @pablodf76 - What are "IAs"?  I've heard of *personal digital assistant* -- but maybe there's a different name and abbreviation for this in Spanish....

Comment: @pablodf76 - Would you take a look at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31573/9385?  Lisa has a good point, "echarle un vistazo" has a dative which is both redundant and implicit, I think.  Do you want to add something here, or should we make a separate canonical q-a about that and refer to it here?  If you want to discuss it at Meta that would be fine too.

Comment: A quote from the answer: "This is a structure that often confuses Spanish learners, since in English and many other languages, body parts and inalienable possessions (...) are indicated by simple possessive pronouns, whereas in Spanish, we prefer (or sometimes need) the sympathetic dative to accomplish the same thing". Could somebody give an example where it is needed? I have never seen any. It seems completely idiomatic to me. I am a Portuguese native speaker, which is similar to Spanish, and we always use possessive pronouns instead of the sympathetic dative.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Examples of that particular structure in Spanish could be the topic for a different question, if there isn't one. As for Portuguese: quando eu estudei português (brasileiro) isso não foi mencionado especialmente, e eu fiquei com a ideia de que o negócio funcionava como em espanhol. Agora eu vejo que estava errado. Ainda assim: a gente não diz *“Eu lavo minhas mãos”*. Se a gente diz *“Eu lavo as mãos”*, aí não tem pronome possessivo. Na verdade não tem nada além do contexto.

Comment: @pablodf76 Tampoco me enseñaron que no se suele usar el pronombre posesivo con partes del cuerpo en español. Creo que nos enseñaron mal. Pequeña corrección: "de qualquer forma" tiene más sentido que "ainda assim" en el texto anterior en portugués.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - Do you mean that it seems completely *un*idiomatic to you? // Te enseñaron mal, desgraciadamente.

Comment: @aparente001 nowadays it doesn't sound odd anymore, but it did when I have traveled in South America and talked to Spanish native speakers for the first time. To be fair with the Spanish course I've taken, I only had one year of classes. It was a relatively short time, but I think that subject should have been explained.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - I agree, this should be one of the basics, and it can be a fun topic in a class.

Comment: @pablodf76 a small suggestion of improvement: mention that the "sympathetic dative" can also be called "possessive dative", which is a *much more* intuitive name. Ref: https://dle.rae.es/dativo