# Existen otros verbos ambiguos con el uso de los pronominales como el verbo “comprar”?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, ambigüedad

Mi pregunta va enfocada a verbos con ambigüedad cuando se usan pronominales en la oración.

Por ejemplo:

> "¿Le compraste el carro a tu hermano?"
>   "Comprale el carro a tu hermano"
>   "Le compre el carro a mi hermano"

Para cada una de estas oraciones tenemos las dos mismas interpretaciones

1. Comprar un carro que era de tu hermano
2. Comprar un carro para tu hermano

¿Existen otros verbos que tengan estas cualidades?

Comment: Creo que "pronominal" no viene al caso aquí.  Cuando leí el título de la pregunta, creí que te referías a frases como "Me compré un nuevo carro" y "Me tomé una siestecita" que igual funcionarían (con el mismo significado) sin la reflexión.  El pronombre pronominal para "Tu compraste" sería "te": "Tú te compraste".

Comment: Correcto, la primera esta incorrecta, no tiene que ver con el pronominal, creo que es inherente del verbo comprar en especifico

Answer (score 4):

Se me ocurren un par de ejemplos. Uno de ellos es *vender*, cuando no queda claro si uno está vendiéndole a otro una cosa que es de uno, o si está vendiendo a un tercero una cosa por cuenta del otro. O sea:

> *Le vendí la casa a mi hermano.*

puede significar

- Le vendí mi casa a mi hermano; mi hermano compró mi casa.
- Vendí la casa de mi hermano a otra persona; mi hermano vendió su casa a través de mí (fui su agente inmobiliario).

También puede ocurrir en algunos casos con el verbo *dar*:

> *Dale el globo a tu hermano.*

puede significar

- Dale a tu hermano su globo; devuélvele su globo a tu hermano.
- Dale a tu hermano tu globo; regálale tu globo a tu hermano.

Del mismo tipo que *vender* puede ser *escribir*:

> *Voy a escribirle una carta a mi abuela.*

puede significar

- Voy a escribir una carta destinada a mi abuela; voy a escribir una carta para mi abuela la lea.
- Voy a escribir una carta de parte de mi abuela para otra persona; mi abuela no puede escribir y me dictará una carta para un tercero.

Seguramente hay más pero me parece que la ambigüedad siempre es de uno o dos tipos y en muy pocos contextos.

Estos son casos donde el pronombre dativo es ambiguo porque además de representar el objeto indirecto también puede señalar alguna otra cosa ([dativo simpatético o ético](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26172/14627)).