# ¿Qué se entiende por la siguiente frase?

Tags: gramática, significado, sintaxis

> María le compró un regalo a Pedro.

Yo entiendo que María compró un regalo *en algún lugar para* Pedro.  Pero si reemplazo "regalo" por "tornillo" y Pedro es ferretero, entendería que Pedro le vendió un tornillo a María. 
Agregaríamos (a mi entender) ambiguedad si la frase fuese

> María le compró una remera a Pedro.

donde no tengo idea qué es lo que debería entender.

¿Es normal y frecuente que el contexto pueda cambiar el significado de la frase de esta manera tan precisa o estoy equivocado y en ambos casos el significado es el mismo? No se me ocurre otro verbo al que le suceda esto.

---

¿Decir "María compró un regalo a Pedro." es incorrecto? No suena bien pero gramaticalmente no le encuentro falla alguna (Sujeto-Verbo-Objeto Directo-Objeto Indirecto). ¿Qué rol juega el ¿pronombre? "le"? ¿No es redundante con "a Pedro"?

Comment: Respecto a la redundancia del pronombre "le", véase: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32243/, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2104/.

Comment: Entonces, las preguntas del último párrafo nada tenían que ver con la duda original. ¿Debería editar la pregunta y borrarlas?

Comment: Duplicado de https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26880/existen-otros-verbos-ambiguos-con-el-uso-de-los-pronominales-como-el-verbo-comp ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efectivamente, el complemento indirecto de *comprar* es ambiguo, ya que puede designar o bien al "destinatario" de la compra (si la compra es un regalo), o bien al vendedor.

En la [Hispanoteca](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/Dativo-%20preposiciones%20a%20y%20para.htm), se explica esta ambigüedad y se da una manera de evitarla:

> Con el verbo *comprar algo a alguien* siempre se dará ambigüedad entre:
>
> - comprar algo para alguien
>
> = ‘comprar algo para regalárselo a alguien’ (finalidad)
>
> - comprar algo a alguien
>
> = ‘comprar algo a alguien que lo vende’ (origen)

Es decir, se puede evitar la ambigüedad usando la preposición *para* cuando se trata de un regalo:

- Voy a comprar un coche para Pedro

Pero si se usa la preposición *a*:

- Le voy a comprar un coche a Pedro

no hay manera de distinguir entre los dos casos sin conocer el contexto.