# The verbs with "se" and without it that mean exactly the same thing

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, gramática, vocabulario

Some verbs have the form with "se" and still mean the same thing and used in the same. For instance:

'comer' and 'comerse' in this sentence:

- Ella se comió el pastel entero.
- Ella comió el pastel entero.

No difference between these sentences?

Is this really the case that some of the verbs can be used with "se" exactly the same way and mean the same thing as the ones without "se"?

The question isn't about the verb "comer" particularly.

Comment: Yes. Search for "dativo ético". There are many questions that have already been asked here on the site.

Comment: Actually it's an "aspectual dative" (for your example; for other verbs and contexts it can be an "ethical dative" as @FGSUZ says). See here (scroll down). https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there/26172#26172