# When to use indirect objects vs prepositions

Tags: traducción, gramática, vocabulario, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos

My understanding of indirect objects is that convey the "to whom" or "for whom" of an action. In English, the indirect object can be used with a preposition (She gave a gift **to me**), or without (She gave **me** a gift). In Spanish, when is it proper to use the indirect object (Ella se lo dijo), and when it is proper to use a preposition (Ella lo compró para él), or when is both or either acceptable?  ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

There are basically three (and a half) different combinations you can use:

1. **Explicit indirect object (uses *a*):** *Di algo a María*
   This is used when the indirect object has yet to be introduced, or it would not be clear from context.
2. **Explicit indirect object (uses *a*) plus pronoun:** *Le di algo a María*
   Identical in meaning to the first.  Used when you haven't introduced who you're giving it to yet.  Particularly emphatic when it comes in front of the verb, but otherwise it's basically fully interchangeable with the (1) with no real difference in interpretation.  If the explicit object is a pronoun (*a mí/ti/él…*) in which case you *must* use both.
3. **Indirect object pronoun:** *Le di algo*
   Used when context makes it clear who it is.  This will be the default if the indirect object is first or second person (*me/te/nos/os*), as the lack of ambiguity makes the redundancy automatically emphatic.
4. **Explicit pseudo-indirect object (uses *para*):** *Di algo para María*
   I label this as pseudo because in Spanish grammar, complements introduced with *para*, though they often fulfill a similar or even identical function as those with *a*, are not considered to be true indirect objects mainly because they are incompatible with the redundant pronoun used, and they allow for some things that the true object doesn't (for example, *nos hice algo* and *hice algo a nosotros* are considered improper, but *hice algo **para** nosotros* is fine).  Furthermore, it can coappear with the *a* (*compré algo a María para sus padres*), and in such a case only the *a* complement can be converted to an indirect object pronoun (*les compré algo a María* doesn't work, but *le compré algo para sus padres* does).

Comment: When studying Portuguese I found that the pseudo-IO with *para* was extremely frequent in places where Spanish would mostly use the regular IO with *a*. That's Brazilian Portuguese; is it true also of European Portuguese? I have to say that *Di algo para María* sounds absolutely wrong to me unless you're speaking of "donating for a cause related to María".

Comment: pablodf76: BP definitely uses *para* more often than EP.  EP uses IO pronouns far more (*dime tu nombre* -> BP *diga seu nome para mi*, EP *diz-me o teu nome*),  which allows for clarification or emphasis through duplication which must be done with *a*.  BP without that technique could more freely choose between *a* and *para* without there being a grammatical *anchor*.

Comment: You're also right that *Di algo para María* sounds weird.  I (a) was probably thinking about what I hear in BP when writing the answer and therefore (b) didn't necessarily choose the best example sentence.  The trick is, of course, that there are a lot of times where *a* and *para* are semantically perfectly interchangeable (and those often tend to line up with where English would use *for*), but there are probably an equally large number of verbs for which it doesn't work.  It'd be interesting to see what the restrictions may be on using that.

Comment: pablodf76 Also (total comment abuse/overload): https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pode-o-complemento-indireto-ser-introduzido-pela-preposicao-para/34597

Comment: I once [noted](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there/26172#26172) that datives of interest can often be spotted because one can turn the IO into a complement with *para* or *por*.