# Why is "te" needed at the end of "pagarte"?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, verbos, conjugación

I am watching the TV show *Gran Hotel* to help my Spanish. At one point one character says to someone they've just met

> La gente solo va a Cantaloa a alojarse o trabajar en el Gran Hotel y tú no parece que puedas pagar**te** una habitación allí.

What is the "te" for at the end of "pagar"? It is already clear that the speaker is talking directly to someone because of the use of "tú" and the conjugation of "parecer" into the third person singular ("parece").

Answer (score 2):

Loosely translated it might be "You do not look as though you could rent yourself a room there". So the suffixed *te* emphasises that the addressee is renting the room for their own occupation.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like a [dative of interest](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26172/14627).