# 'no me sé' y 'me la mira'

Tags: gramática, pronombres, sintaxis, reflexivos

Encuentro en unas canciones de Ozuna que a veces él usa el pronombre 'me' más de lo que a mí me parece normal. Por ejemplo, en la canción "La Modelo" canta:

> Yo no me sé ni su nombre, pero la quiero

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre 'Yo no me sé ni su nombre' y 'Yo no sé ni su nombre'?

También canta en la canción "Única":

> Todo el mundo me la mira

¿Cuál es la diferencia aquí entre 'Todo el mundo me la mira' y 'Todo el mundo la mira'?

Perdonen que no conozco las reglas gramaticales muy bien y principalmente solo lo que me suena correcto :)

Comment: See the canonical q-a at https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26171/9385.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando un verbo aparece junto con un pronombre reflexivo aunque el significado no es reflexivo, se lo llama **verbo pronominal**.¹ Algunos son obligatoriamente pronominales, otros opcionales, y generalmente hay un cambio de significado sutil entre la forma básica y la forma con pronombre. *Saber* es un verbo opcionalmente pronominal.

La forma pronominal transitiva *saberse (algo)* significa "haber llegado a saber, haber memorizado (algo), haber aprendido (algo) conscientemente hasta saberlo bien". En el contexto de esta canción, *yo no me sé ni su nombre*, quizá signifique "yo no he podido averiguar su nombre (aunque quise, aunque lo intenté)". Se podría omitir el pronombre y decir simplemente *yo no sé su nombre*; no cambiaría mucho el significado, pero sonaría un poco más impersonal. *Saber algo* no indica ningún esfuerzo ni ningún logro. Por ejemplo:

- *El niño ya sabe unas palabras.* = El niño ya conoce algunas palabras, ya habla un poco, ya dice cosas.
- *El niño ya se sabe unas palabras.* = El niño ya aprendió algunas palabras, ya adquirió algo de vocabulario, ya logra expresarse.

*Todo el mundo me la mira* es una frase ambigua. Viendo la letra de la canción, el significado se aclara: lo que está diciendo es que todo el mundo la mira (a la mujer), y que eso le afecta personalmente a él (al que canta). Es un caso de **dativo ético** ([tema difícil](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there)) con algo de **dativo simpatético**. En pocas palabras: *todo el mundo me la mira* significa

1. que todo el mundo mira a la mujer pero esto también involucra a quien canta, le produce algún sentimiento (celos, incomodidad, etc.);
2. que el cantante ve a la mujer de manera posesiva, como si fuera parte o propiedad suya o como a un miembro de su familia.

Como antes, podría decir *todo el mundo la mira* (sin el pronombre *me*), y el significado sería el mismo pero sin el toque de involucramiento personal o posesividad que mencioné arriba.

Si el cantante tuviese una nariz muy grande y todo el mundo se quedara mirando su nariz, la frase también podría ser *todo el mundo me la mira*. Es el mismo tipo de estructura que cuando decimos *me lavo la cara, me ato los zapatos, me lastimé la mano, me golpeé la cabeza*.

¹ En diccionarios aparecen citados en infinitivo más *-se* (por ejemplo, *saberse*), y se indican como *pron.* o *prnl.* o algo similar.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Esa explicación fue perfecto

Comment: Fantástica explicación. Es curioso porque en España la frase _el niño ya se sabe unas palabras_ suena rara, no se usa.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Y *el niño ya se sabe las tablas (de multiplicar)*?

Comment: Sí, esta sí suena bien. Estoy pensando que también usamos _yo me la he visto_ cuando hablamos de una serie de televisión, por ejemplo (_¡Me la he visto entera!_ especialmente).

Comment: @fedorqui *Yo me la he visto entera* es dativo aspectual. Como *Me he comido toda la pizza*.