# ¿Es "me quisiera saber" gramaticalmente correcto?

Tags: pronombres, reflexivos

Hasta donde tengo entendido, la forma correcta es "quisiera saber". He observado, sin embargo, hace un momento una oración de una colega en la que se dice más o menos lo siguiente:

> En primer lugar me quisiera saber qué opinión te merece el tema X.

¿Existe alguna posibilidad gramatical para esta oración?

Comment: No soy un experto en gramática, pero, me quisiera saber no es gramaticalmente correcto y ademas se oye super raro. La forma correcta sería "yo quisiera saber", ya que el verbo "quisiera" esta conjugado en la primera persona del singular. Aunque, como la conjugación es obvia el pronombre se puede omitir.

Comment: @walen - ¿Puede haber algo asi para "te merece"?

Comment: @walen - Gracias.  Si es así, entonces me pregunto si este uso de *quisiera* es parecido.  Quizás la colega lo veía un poco como *me pregunto*.  Para mi, los dos usos son un poco raros....

Comment: También pensaba que tal vez sería un uso reflexivo de *saber* que desconocía (tipo *enterarse*) pero resulta que no, parece que no hay ningún uso reflexivo registrado ni en el DLE ni en el DAA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el ejemplo citado, *me quisiera saber* es un error. El verbo *querer* no funciona como verbo pronominal de esta manera, ni tampoco *saber* en este contexto.

Usando *querer* uno puede decir, por ejemplo, *Si ella me quisiera* o incluso *si yo me quisiera a mí mismo*, donde el pronombre *me* es un objeto directo (normal en el primer caso, reflexivo en el segundo).

Usando otro verbo dependiente de *querer* uno podría decir, por ejemplo, *yo me quisiera sentar*, con una trasposición¹ del pronombre que más habitualmente iría pospuesto al infinitivo del verbo pronominal *sentar(se)*, o sea:

> *yo me quisiera sentar* = *yo quisiera sentarme*

*Saber* tiene una forma pronominal: *[saberse](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30251/14627)* significa "haberse aprendido; saber de memoria; saber porque uno se esforzó para aprender". Pero en el contexto de la frase del ejemplo (*yo me quisiera saber qué opinión te merece...*) esta forma no tiene sentido:

> *yo quisiera *saberme qué opinión te merece...*

...porque la semántica del verbo *saberse* no se corresponde con la de una pregunta indirecta, como es ésta. Si uno desea información dice *yo quiero/quisiera saber* o *me gustaría saber* o algo similar. Una frase posible, pero muy rara, sería

> *Yo me quisiera saber tu opinión sobre el tema X.*

El significado de esto sería diferente: querría decir "yo quisiera haberme enterado de y memorizado tu opinión sobre el tema X".

---

¹ No recuerdo cómo se llama esto en castellano; en inglés es *[raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_(linguistics))*.

Comment: ¿Qué hay de la frase "Me quisiera saber todas las capitales del mundo"? Por alguna razón no me suena incorrecta, aunque "Quisiera saberme todas las capitales del mundo" probablemente sea lo más usado.

Comment: @MauricioMartinez Ambas estarían bien (no sabría decir cuál es más usada). La diferencia con el ejemplo es que "las capitales del mundo" es algo que uno puede aprender o memorizar (=saberse).