# Is there a difference in meaning between "echar un vistazo a" and "echarle un vistazo a"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronombres, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

I was recently watching [**a Spanish language video**](https://youtu.be/lO9X-7beRa8?list=PLxQbwssWGRBZ4KtO9euVRRwAqxgguoLlW&t=48) that included the phrase "echarle un vistazo a."  It made me wonder if the "le" was required or optional.  Once I found evidence that both seem to be fairly frequently used,

[image]

I got to wondering if there was any difference in meaning between the two.  In other words, is there a situation in which "echarle un vistazo a" would be the better choice?

---

*Addendum: The thread for [**"All about datives, or: What's that funny “le” or “me” doing in there?"**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there) makes no mention of the redundant indirect object pronoun, which (seeing as how that is the only difference between the two variants I include) is at the core of this question.  When I went to tag this question, I was actually on the hunt for "redundant pronoun," but not finding any, and seeing that only 200 or so questions had been tagged with the larger category "pronombres," I tagged it as such not knowing whether or not enough questions would ever be submitted to this forum on the much more specific topic of the "redundant pronoun."*

---

**¿Hay una diferencia en sentido entre "echar un vistazo a" y "echarle un vistazo a"?**

Hace poco vi [**un vídeo para estudiantes de español**](https://youtu.be/lO9X-7beRa8?list=PLxQbwssWGRBZ4KtO9euVRRwAqxgguoLlW&t=48) que incluyó la frase "echarle un vistazo a".  Me hizo preguntarme si "le" se requiere o es opcional.  Una vez encontré evidencia que las dos frases parecen utilizarse con bastante frecuencia [véanse arriba], me puse a pensar si hay alguna diferencia entre las dos.  En otras palabras, ¿hay una situación en que "echarle un vistazo a" sería la mejor opción?

---

*Adición: El hilo para [**"All about datives, or: What's that funny “le” or “me” doing in there?"**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there) no hace ninguna mención del pronombre indirecto redundante, que (viendo como ésa es la única diferencia entre las dos frases que incluyo) es fundamental a esta pregunta.  Cuando fui a dar "tags" a esta pregunta, en realidad estaba a la caza de "redundant pronoun", pero, ya que no encontré ningún tag con esa etiqueta, y viendo que menos que 300 preguntas se han dado la etiqueta más grande de "pronombres," le di a esta pregunta esta etiqueta porque no podía concebir de la necesidad para una etiqueta más específica.*

Comment: There is a canonical Q-A about optional datives: [All about datives, or: What's that funny "le" or "me" doing in there?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there).  I'd like to see some reference to the canonical Q-A in your question, as part of the "show your research."

Comment: @aparente001  The link to the video and the Google Ngram was my research.  My fruitless search for an answer to my question does not make for easy citation, nor would it serve a purpose.  According to the rules set forth for posting a question, we should all probably assume that, unless the question is a duplicate or easily found on the web, a person who posts here has done at least that much.  If there is some sort of magical rubric of research one must consult before daring to post a question here, please let us know what this magical rubric is.

Comment: for now i'm voting for the duplicate on the basis that i believe it falls into the "dative of interest" class: Ella le cocinó un plato especial. = "She cooked a special dish (for him).", if you want to argue against it please @ me so i can take my vote away if i get convinced.

Comment: I can understand your frustration, Lisa.  But don't despair.  Closed questions can and do get reopened.  The key is to take the feedback on board and edit the question, explaining how the referenced Q-A doesn't completely resolve things for you.

Comment: In my defense, "All about datives ..." does not address the redundant indirect object.  Furthermore, as a student of Spanish (and I have to question whether or not any of those who voted to close this question are students of Spanish as in native English speakers attempting to learn Spanish), a title with "dative" in the title isn't all that likely to generate interest ... even with the "What's that funny ..." tacked on to the end of it.  Just my 2 cents FWIW.  I'm beginning to think that moderation isn't fully taking the audience for this forum into consideration.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I went carefully through our canonical question about datives today and realized that I agree with Lisa that there's nothing there that would explicitly explain why the funny "le" is there in "echarle un ojo." I think there are several things going on with "echarle un ojo." **1** The indirect object referred to by "le" could be implicit, perhaps "the problem" in a general sense. There is a good q-a about this (something like "se lo dí" which I am not finding right now). **2** When the speaker includes le, he is in a sense owning the problem, and this can reassure the ...

Comment: ... listener that the speaker is taking the problem seriously and truly wants to help. I'm glad you reviewed the canonical q-a, Lisa, but I don't think it's enough to understand this use of *le*. I will ping Pablo over there to see if he wants to expand the answer, but in the meantime, I am voting to reopen here. // Sorry I wrote "echarle un ojo" -- the question was about "echarle un vistazo" -- but they're synonymous anyway.

Comment: This is IMNSHO **not** a duplicate question. I don't know what the answer is (and it's Sunday afternoon and I'm just back from vacations) but it's a matter of whether a redundant IO pronoun is optional; it's not a "special" dative.

Answer (score 4):

Si omitimos la referencia explícita al objeto indirecto, "echar un vistazo" tiene un sentido más general que "echar**le** un vistazo":

> *—Se ha fundido la bombilla.*
>
> 1. *—Voy a echar un vistazo.* → Sentido general: revisar los fusibles, cuadro de luces, la bombilla en sí... No especifica.
> 2. *—Voy a echarle un vistazo.* → Implica que se refiere a la bombilla.

Sin embargo, cuando el objeto directo va explícito en la misma frase, el pronombre "le" se hace redundante, y por tanto "echar un vistazo **a ...**" y "echar**le** un vistazo **a ...**" se vuelven completamente equivalentes:

> *—Se ha ido la luz.*
>   *—Voy a echar(le) un vistazo a la bombilla.*

Comment: Good answer, but I'm going to give others a chance to answer before I award the green check mark.  For starters, if you'll notice my tags and my examples, I am specifically looking for explanations that involve examples that include both a direct and indirect object.  For example, "... take a look at the book ..." or "... take a look at the house ..." or "... take a look at this list ..."  (You get the idea.)  Thanks for your initial attempt, though.  Even without any additional explanation, I found it interesting and of value.

Comment: Well, if you want the green check mark, I would say that would definitely be a step toward obtaining it.  True, I did not specifically request for information about the DO and IO, but my question was tagged as such and furthermore, my examples both included an "a" at the end.  Your answer did not provide examples that matched those I had given in my question.

Comment: And, while I am at it, I suppose (though I wasn't perhaps aware of this at the time), that I was hoping someone could address the "le" and its purpose (with respect to what I now realize is the indirect object).

Comment: I know that now because I happened to find a hard copy of a Spanish grammar book that, likely, not everyone has access to.  Now that I've found this grammar book and have more understanding than what I had before, I suppose I could just delete this question and let other students of Spanish figure it out on their own.  Truthfully, though, I was hoping someone on this forum could provide a thorough explanation that went beyond what I happened to find in this grammar book I found.

Comment: Furthermore, and Krauss below addresses this, the grammar book I've mentioned also adds that "In the spoken language native speakers would consider [the absence of the redundant pronoun] odd," which explains why I've already seen examples where the redundant pronoun variant is _more_ common. For an example, see this Ngram [**here**](https://bit.ly/2nH8MIR). However, I'm still confused as to why it is sometimes more common and other times is not. Does someone reading this know of any good rule of thumb (or does knowing when to use which just require extensive exposure to the Spanish language?).

Comment: Upon closer inspection, I see now that your answer somewhat mirrors the one Krauss gave.  His approach was slightly different, however, and was a bit easier for me to follow.  If no one else steps in to answer, I may wind up giving him the green check mark simply for the fact that he adds that adding "le" sounds more natural (and that supports what I've read in this grammar book of mine).  Plus, he has fewer reputation points than you.  (Good golly!  You've got more than 20,000!  ¡Enhorabuena!)

Comment: Yes, walen, specificity is good, but I purposely didn't want to get all that specific. I wanted to open the door to a good answer rather than box it in with a narrowly defined scope. The fact that nobody has yet chimed in with an answer addressing the redundant indirect object is a bit disappointing, but, at the same time, it tells me a lot about the experience/background of those who took the time/effort to answer. It tells me that they are, quite likely, native speakers, but not necessarily credentialed educators.

Comment: (cont.) While I appreciate the answers that have been given, I was kind of hoping that I'd get one that was more on the level of oh, say, pablodf76, Gustavson, guifa, Yay, .... But, even if I don't, I do appreciate the answers that have been given thus far.

Comment: (cont.) Sometimes, when you get really specific with a request, you get exactly what you've asked for and nothing more. Most of the time, I want more, even if I don't know exactly what that is, and I want to give the person who answers the freedom to give me the details that he/she thinks would be useful to me (or anyone else who stumbles upon this thread).

Comment: Walen, you make some excellent points.  It is likely the reason I haven't gone green check mark crazy and doled it out.  As I think I may have mentioned, I was hoping someone might mention the redundant indirect object and cite some sources.  Based on your comments, I think I'll let this simmer just a bit more.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: When speaking, I would use the suffix **le**. It's more natural.
Respuesta rápida: Usar **le** me suena más natural.

---

Para comenzar **le** es un pronombre indeterminado que funciona como objeto directo; considera los siguientes ejemplos:

> **Echa** un vistazo   *(Frase imperativa genérica que no especifica el objeto relacionado)*
>
> **Échale** un vistazo *(El sufijo **le** indica un objeto indeterminado)*

Para aclarar un poco mejor el punto considera los siguientes ejemplos

> No sé donde dejé las llaves...
>   Por favor, **echa** un vistazo.  *(No hay objeto, asumimos que son las llaves pero la orden no especifica categóricamente que quieren que busquemos las llaves)*

O

> Compré un carro nuevo...
>   **Échale** un vistazo.  *(Aunque el sufijo **le** es indeterminado, el contexto nos dice inequívocamente que quieren que veamos el carro nuevo)*

Con la lógica anterior, me inclino por incluir el sufijo **le** para el caso de tu pregunta:

> **Échale** un vistazo al nuevo carro que compré. *(Frase equivalente al ejemplo anterior que introduce el contexto al final)*

---

Si cambiamos el verbo podemos ver como omitir **le** nos introduce una incertidumbre:

> - El niño tiene frío... pon**le** un súeter   *(Uso trivial, definitivamente **le** es obligatorio para dar este significado)*
> - Pon**le** suéter al niño  *(Uso trivial)*
> - Pon suéter al niño        *(Me suena muy extraño ¿Dónde quieres que ponga la ropa exáctamente?)*
> - Pon un suéter junto a la mochila del niño *(¡Espera! ¿Seguimos hablando del niño?)*
> - Pon**le** un suéter al niño junto a su mochila  *(equivalente al ejemplo anterior pero con los roles de objeto directo y objeto indirecto intercambiados)*

Comment: Interesting answer and since it touches more on what I was looking for and provides examples closer to what I had in my original question, you are definitely a contender for the green check mark. After reading just a portion of your answer I'm beginning to wonder if the inclusion of "le" in such phrases is somewhat like the difference between "esto" and "éste." (Since 2010, the variant with the accented "e" has been optional, as I would assume you are aware, Krauss, but someone else reading this might not be. I only add it here as an example to help me get a feel for when I should use "le.")