# Question regarding the use dative case with indirect object pronoun "le"

Tags: gramática, objetos-indirectos

Good afternoon,

I have read the [canonical question about datives](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there) and seem to understand examples and differences of dative case types with indirect object pronouns.

But I still cannot understand how these 2 examples below are formed. Could you please help, explaining this, and saying which of 4 types of dative cases these examples belong to (regarding use of "le" and "les" here):

1) "Los hombres de Doyle le tienen miedo" - Doyle's guys are scared of him. Here "le" is not used in the meaning "him". So why simply not to say like this: "Los hombres de Doyle tiene miedo de él".

2) Same here, but in plural: "¿No les temes?" - "And are you not scared of them?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Will check for this tag. So the use of "le" in these sentences does not apply to dative cases explanation. This is different topic. I understand now.

Comment: That canonical q-a page is intended to clear up "funny" datives, i.e. the use of ostensibly dative complements for grammatical roles other than a straightforward indirect object. So if a verb just normally takes an indirect object, that page won't have any explanation for that.

Comment: Yeah. I really didn't know before that there are some complicated verbs that could employ indirect object pronouns (like temer). As I already said, it helps me now to figuratively translate "you show your fears for them" (thus making a case for using indirect object pronoun) and literally "you are afraid of them". Or I just need to remember such verbs (like a chunk of words). I think there are not that many complicated verbs like temer, but if I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: I myself hadn't noticed the oddity of *temer* at first. I wouldn't know if there are many such verbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example shows a couple of confusions.

> 1) "Los hombres de Doyle le tienen miedo" - Doyle's guys are scared of him. Here "le" is not used in the meaning "him". So why simply not to say like this: "Los hombres de Doyle tiene miedo de él".

It seems here you are trying to translate literally from English, and also mixing up two alternative syntaxes for the idiomatic phrase *tener miedo*. You'll understand it better with simpler examples using some imaginary characters Alice and Bob:

1. *Alice tiene miedo de Bob.*
2. *Alice le tiene miedo a Bob.*

Both of these mean "Alice fears Bob; Alice is afraid/scared of Bob". In #1 we use a complement headed by *de*. In #2 we use an indirect object, which (as usual) is preceded by *a*. In the latter example we also have to use *le*, even though it looks redundant, because that's a rule (*Alice tiene miedo a Bob* is ungrammatical). If we replace Bob by a pronoun, we have:

1. *Alice tiene miedo de él.*
2. *Alice le tiene miedo a él.*

In this version of #2, adding *a él* is emphatic. If the context is such that it's already clear who is being referred to (*él*), the last part becomes truly redundant and you could leave it out:

2. *Alice le tiene miedo.*

We would only add *a él* in this case if we want to emphasize that Alice is afraid of "him" and not of somebody else.

As for the second example:

> 2) Same here, but in plural: "¿No les temes?" - "And are you not scared of them?"

Here we have the verb *temer*, not the phrase *tener miedo*. *Temer* is a somewhat complicated verb because [it can be used as transitive or intransitive but with an indirect object](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=temer). The latter is more common, especially when speaking of fear of people, and that's what's happening here. That's why it's *¿No les temes?* and not *¿No los temes?*. It works the same as the second pattern that we've seen for *tener miedo*.

The emphatic version would add a redundant pronoun:

> *¿No les temes **a ellos**?*

If we wanted to name the people you fear explicitly, we'd have to do it as above:

> *¿No les temes **a los hombres de Doyle**?*

I hope this clarifies your doubts a bit. If not, just say so in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for thorough explanation. I now understand. I actually know grammar regarding the use of indirect object pronouns. But I always thought of them in the context of dative case. So when I saw sentence "no les temes", it confused me, because here is no dative case and I thought "les" should not be used here in the first place (never). Now I understand it is used mostly because of the complicated verb temer.
Even though we can figuratively translate as "don't give them fears" (for tener miedo and temer).
I think it is solved.

Comment: @aparente001 No, I'm talking about the #2 above; the indirect object is *a Bob*.

Comment: I don't know how I managed to misread that first pair.  I read them three times, and I got it wrong all three times.

Comment: I think I will delete my comments -- they're obsolete now.