# ¿Cuándo está permitido elidir el objeto directo de verbos como “decir” en España y en Latinoamérica?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, sintaxis, objetos-directos

Estaba buscando material para plantear una pregunta sobre verbos que llevan objeto indirecto (dativo) sin llevar objeto directo, como el uso más común de *temer* ~ *tener miedo* (inspirado en [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31656/question-regarding-the-use-dative-case-with-indirect-object-pronoun-le)), y me encuentro con un hilo en [cierto foro](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/objeto-indirecto-sin-objeto-directo.1867658/post-9329050) donde se plantea una posible diferencia regional respecto de la opcionalidad del objeto directo.

El diálogo planteado como ejemplo de elisión permitida de un objeto directo utiliza el verbo *decir* (en el sentido de "avisar"):

> - Tu mamá me había dicho que pasara a su casa a tomar café, pero creo que no voy a poder.
>   - ¡Ah! Bueno, no te preocupes. Voy a **decirle**.

Quien escribe es de Costa Rica. Para mí (que soy de Argentina) el ejemplo es perfectamente correcto. Sin embargo, otro usuario dice que en España esta elisión del OD no está permitida:

> En España, por lo menos, eso no es correcto. Sería: Voy a **decírselo**.

Otro:

> Me parece que en España la respuesta se vería inconclusa. "Voy a decirle... ¿qué?". Nosotros diríamos "Voy a **decírselo**" (o sea, OI + OD).

¿Es esto así? ¿Se considera incorrecto en España (o en algún otro lugar) omitir el objeto directo de *decir*? ¿Qué ocurre con otros verbos similares? ¿Hay alguna regla general (más allá de lo que digan los diccionarios sobre la transitividad de cada verbo) sobre cuándo se puede o no se puede elidir un objeto?

Comment: ¡Que interesante! Para complementar la pregunta, el «voy a decirle» en Colombia suena bien pero usamos más **«Yo le digo»** o **«Le voy a decir»** también sin OD.

Comment: @DGaleano Acá también se usan esas variantes, supongo que eligiendo según el énfasis o la eufonía.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que finalmente voy a responder mi propia pregunta... Como no tengo acceso especial a material académico, fuera de lo libremente disponible en internet, me cuesta hacerme un panorama completo, pero efectivamente existe una gradación en la tendencia a la elisión de los objetos directos, donde

- el español peninsular estándar es la variedad más conservadora y restrictiva, permitiendo rara vez la elisión del OD;
- el rioplatense ocupa un lugar intermedio, aunque con reglas también bastante estrictas;
- otras variedades americanas (como la andina), junto con el castellano de la zona de influencia vasca, permiten la elisión del OD con criterios pragmáticos amplios.

El panorama está bastante bien trazado en *[The Interplay of Variation and Change in Contact Settings](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=q8iYJOmrR_0C&lpg=PA179&ots=nrilxb_258&dq=direct%20object%20elision%20in%20spanish&pg=PA181#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (libro del cual lamentablemente Google Books no muestra un par de páginas importantes).

El español europeo estándar sólo permite elidir un objeto directo **cuando su referente es indefinido y no lleva artículo** (cito ejemplos del libro mencionado).

> --¿Has comprado *revistas*?
> --Sí, he comprado, sí.

Esta elisión restringida sería la forma básica, primitiva, de la estructura de la frase. Tiene sentido que se mantenga como estándar de la zona central de origen del idioma.

El dialecto rioplatense es algo más flexible: además de los OD indefinidos, permite elidir un objeto directo definido **cuando en la misma frase hay otros dos argumentos** (generalmente, pero no siempre, sujeto y objeto indirecto), y también con verbos como *conocer* y *saber*.

> Si le digo, me mata.
> Si le digo que le dijiste, es capaz de no volver.
> Las cataratas del Iguazú son sorprendentes, ¿conocés?

El rioplatense no innovó demasiado con respecto al estándar peninsular. Los investigadores opinan que los cambios en la elisión del OD son de origen interno (es decir, provienen de tendencias ya presentes en la lengua). El núcleo de la región rioplatense no recibió una gran influencia de las lenguas amerindias.

Formas más amplias de elisión del OD se dan en variedades como el español andino, que va desde el norte de Argentina pasando por Bolivia, Perú, Ecuador y hasta partes de Colombia, donde influye el quechua (lengua de los líderes del imperio inca). Ocurren cosas similares en el español de Paraguay (por influencia del guaraní), y en variedades centroamericanas en contacto con las lenguas mayas. El castellano del País Vasco presenta una tendencia similar. En todos los casos el castellano ha estado y sigue estando en contacto (a veces en situaciones de bilingüismo habitual) con idiomas con una morfología radicalmente diferente, cuyos rasgos tienden a la elisión de objetos directos. (Por ejemplo, en el caso del guaraní simplemente no existen pronombres átonos de objeto directo.)

En el sistema del español paraguayo el objeto directo se elide con frecuencia, **con la única condición de que su referente sea inanimado**. Por ejemplo:

> Él pensaba comercializar con la *energía* vendiendo a otros países.
>
> Las *casas* no aguantan y luego ya al abandonar, se pudren todo.
>
> El *vestido de novia* a lo mejor compra el novio, compra la novia.
>
> Antes no teníamos *policía* ni tampoco necesitábamos. Cuando comenzamos a necesitar, ya no servía.

(Quiero mencionar que el primero y el último de estos ejemplos me resulta totalmente correcto a mí; no sé si a otros hablantes rioplatenses.)

El español andino es todavía más permisivo en la elisión, pero no tengo los detalles. En [un paper sobre el tema](https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/CLAC/article/download/48469/45294) se menciona que en general (no sólo en el español andino) ocurre que

> ...los objetos nulos son altamente topicales, son los marcadores de
> accesibilidad más altos, por lo que el emisor cree que el oyente puede
> asignarles fácilmente un referente. Así, la accesibilidad y la
> continuidad topical del referente son esenciales en la omisión. Los
> rasgos semánticos del objeto definitud, especificidad y animacidad
> parecen tener un papel igualmente relevante en la omisión, así como
> los entornos sintácticos de tematización del referente, polaridad
> negativa, referentes oracionales, presencia del dativo o
> construcciones de infinitivo, o la clase semántica del verbo.

Algo similar parece ocurrir [en el castellano del País Vasco](https://webs.ucm.es/info/circulo/no61/camus.pdf).

Todos estos fenómenos ocurren más allá de que los consideremos "correctos" o no. En muchos de los casos más "extremos" resulta obvio que no tienen cabida en la norma culta, pero la norma culta es por supuesto una convención.

Answer (score 2):

En el Español peninsular, como norma general, no es "recomendable" la omisión del O.D. salvo que quede implícito. En su ejemplo:

```
- Tu mamá me había dicho que pasara a su casa a tomar café, pero creo que no voy a poder.
- ¡Ah! Bueno, no te preocupes. Voy a decirle.
```

Con las respuesta se indica que se le va a decir a ella (-le) el mensaje ("que no voy a poder pasar a su casa a tomar café"), que es el OD.

En el ejemplo en Español peninsular:

```
- Tu mamá me había dicho que pasara a su casa a tomar café, pero creo que no voy a poder.
- ¡Ah! Bueno, no te preocupes. Voy a decírselo.
```

Se da por implícito el OI en la forma reflexiva (la madre) y se emplea el OD (-lo equivale al mensaje de "no voy a poder pasar a su casa a tomar café"). También se puede emplear:

```
- Tu mamá me había dicho que pasara a su casa a tomar café, pero creo que no voy a poder.
- ¡Ah! Bueno, no te preocupes. Yo se lo digo.
```

Se da por implícito el OI en la forma reflexiva y el OD re refleja en el -lo. El problema de su ejemplo es que decir es un verbo transitivo, por lo que, a priori, necesita de OD.

Relacionado con su pregunta: [CVC. Foros](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=51468)

Answer (score 0):

*Decir* is a transitive verb according [this web site](//www.ejemplos.co/100-ejemplos-de-verbos-transitivos-e-intransitivos/).

By the same source, **transitive verb requires direct object**, rendering its elision a non canonical variant, which was the actual point of [the forum folk](//forum.wordreference.com/threads/objeto-indirecto-sin-objeto-directo.1867658/post-9330363).

Whenever things are factually alright, there *should* be no such thing as *formally incorrect*. Maybe in other knowledge disciplines, not in pure and simple communication.

---

*Decirle* is verb + indirect object. Non canonical variant according to [the linked source](//www.ejemplos.co/100-ejemplos-de-verbos-transitivos-e-intransitivos/).

*Decírselo* is verb + indirect object + direct object. Canonical according to [the linked source](//www.ejemplos.co/100-ejemplos-de-verbos-transitivos-e-intransitivos/), good as per [the forum folk](//forum.wordreference.com/threads/objeto-indirecto-sin-objeto-directo.1867658/post-9330363).

---

#### What verbs are transitive.

<del>**Theory**</del> (I know I knew, but I don't remember anymore<sup>1</sup>). **Just any non intransitive verb**<sup>2</sup>.

#### What verbs are intransitive.

**No direct object is applicable**. One *muere*, not <del>*muere* a alguien</del>, but *le hace morir*, or more poetically, *le da muerte*. Nonetheless, one *mata*, but there's someone, or something, that is killed.

In summary, *morir* is intransitive, *matar* is transitive.

---

Example transitives: *matar*, *decir*, *mirar*...

Example "corresponding/sibling/related" intransitives: *morir*, *hablar*, *ver*...

---

[spain](/questions/tagged/spain)

All that written, with that non canonical variant you will be well understood in any european Spanish spoken variant. If you are writing, consider all of the issue in topic; if you are speaking, focus on fluency more than correctness.

---

<sub>1: I studied this when I was a small kiddo, many many years ago. Those years the *be* and *uve* phonetic difference would be obsolete already, but most isolated and / or oldest educators would still stick to the antique doctrines.</sub>

<sub>2: Prove me wrong.</sub>