# Using se and le together in "se le va a hacer largo" (hacerse largo)

Tags: gramática, objetos-indirectos

I'm trying to understand the structure and grammar behind "se le va a hacer largo" in this article:

https://www.eladelantado.com/castilla-y-leon/ibanez-en-su-aislamiento-tras-el-positivo-se-me-va-a-hacer-largo/

But I am struggling with both the meaning of this expression and in particular the meaning of se.

Can someone please explain this? Is se a reflexive pronoun in this case?

Comment: This article deals with "hacerse largo" so it might help you: https://howlearnspanish.com/short-spanish-lesson-1/

Comment: This helps a lot.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hacerse* means "to make itself [into]", "to become", "to turn". It is used generally with adjectives. For example, *hacerse largo* = "to become long". This *se* is reflexive, even though the meaning of the expression is not necessarily reflexive. If a leaf turns red in autumn, it's not that the leaf is doing something to itself in order to change color. It's the same with *hacerse* in Spanish.

By adding an indirect object pronoun (like *le*), the expression shows **for whom the change is relevant**. Thus, *“se hace largo”* means "it becomes long", but *“se le hace largo”* means "it becomes long for him/her", or more idiomatically "it feels long to him/her".

> *“Esta cuarentena se me hizo interminable.”* =
> “This quarantine felt endless to me.”

This is a kind of [ethical dative](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there/26172#26172).

Comment: Ok, this helps me understand this much better.  Thank you.