# Uso particular de dativo para decir "take from somebody"

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Vi las siguientes oraciones:

1. De una película "Contratiempo" (España):

*La cartera del chaval. **Se** la cogí antes de cargarlo en el maletero.*

2. De un libro "El arte de no amargarse la vida" (España):

*Cuando tengamos que hablar en público y eso nos suscite algún temor, podemos sacudír**nos**lo pensando que nuestra imagen —basada en logros o habilidades— no es importante.*

Preguntas:

1. ¿En la primera oración "se" fue usado para decir que la cartera fue cogida del chaval (from him)?
2. ¿En la segunda oración pronombre "nos" en "sacudírnoslo" fue usado para decir que podamos quitarnos el temor (literalmente - "shake it off from ourselves")? O en este caso simplemente la forma reflexiva fue usada (sacudirse) con pronombre "lo"? De hecho, creo que esto fue usado como el verbo reflexivo.

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pienso que los dos ejemplos que muestras son casos particulares de otros tipos de dativos, y que el significado de "apartar algo de uno mismo" viene dado por el verbo.

En el primer caso,

- Le cogí la cartera

yo interpreto "le" como un [dativo simpatético/posesivo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26172/24236), que indica que "la cartera" es una "posesión inalienable". Se podría perfectamente decir:

- Le sujeté la cartera mientras se cambiaba

o

- Le rompí la cartera sin querer

donde el significado del dativo "le" no es necesariamente "quitar algo a alguien".

En el segundo caso,

- Podemos sacudirnos el temor

el verbo "[sacudirse](https://dle.rae.es/sacudir)", en forma pronominal, significa (acepción 4):

> 4. tr. Arrojar, tirar o despedir algo o apartarlo violentamente de sí. U. t. c. prnl.

donde **U. t. c. prnl.** significa" usado también como pronominal", es decir, con pronombre "se" (o "nos" en este caso).