# How can an Indirect Object Pronoun show possession?

Tags: adjetivos, objetos-indirectos, posesivos

I was wondering how to say *"I cut his hair"* in Spanish. I thought it would be something along the lines of *"Corté su pelo"*. However, when I went to Google Translate, what I got was:

> Le corté el pelo

This would be literally translated as "(to) him I cut the hair", which is awkward-sounding but I get the point. **What I don't get is how an ID pronoun can show posession.** I read the [canonical answer on this forum](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there) and apparently it's called "dativo posesivo", but I couldn't understand a single word it was saying. When I looked it up on Google, I can hardly find any reliable resources in English.

**What is this phenomenon and can someone please go into detail about it?** Why can't I say "Corté su pelo"? Is it because "su" is too general? What about the notorious "Me duele la cabeza" (*me* being an indirect object pronoun) (Literally, the head hurts me/To me the head hurts)? **Is it grammatically correct to say "La cabeza me duele" (*me* being a direct object pronoun)?**

Comment: I agree that the first few times you meet the sympathetic dative it seems odd to speakers of other languages but I do not think you are helping yourself by trying to translate it literally.  Spanish pronouns are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Corté <s>su</s> pelo.

I seem to remember someone saying "**Le** corte **su** pelito," but in a more playful way. If you say "su pelo" without providing any additional information, then that sounds to me artificial, just like a dubbed movie or something that is wrong in my variety.

- Le corté **su** pelo lo mejor que pude.
- Le corto **su** pelo cada vez que me lo pide/cada vez que puedo.
- Le corto **su** pelo hace años.

The use of "su" without the "le" sounds unnatural for me, although the omission of the indirect object is grammatically correct. The possesive pronoun also includes a meaning of familiarity and closeness, signaling that the subject is well known and close to the clients.

> - **Le** corto **el** pelo cuando tengo tiempo (better).

The dative possessive(DT) indicates who owns the body part or possession and it must appear with a **definite article(DA)(el, la, los, las)** instead of the **possessive pronouns(PP)(my, mine, yours, his, hers, ours and theirs)**.

> (Yo)[subject] corté (el)(DA) pelo[DO] (un tiempo)

> Corté pelo en su/esa época.

The meaning of the verb cortar is realized in the subject Yo, the one who cuts someone's hair, but it can be omitted.
But if, instead, **there's no indirect object** in this sentence, then it suggests that the person actually worked as a hairdresser for some time or for a time.

I'd say:

> (Yo) **Le(IO=a él/ella)** corté **el(DA)** **pelo(DO)** => I cut **his/her(PP)** **hair(DO)** => I gave **him/her(I0)** a **haircut(DO)**

> Le corta el pelo => Someone else cuts his/her hair.

Anyway, to me, this sentence wouldn't make much sense without a 'le.'

> ¡ME duele la cabeza! => A mí la cabeza duele(no one says it like that) => **My(PP)** head hurts.

In this case, just as the comment above says, "a mí" can be replaced by "me".

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: It doesn't show possession.

You can start with a canonical sentence like "*escribí una carta a mi abuela*" where you have the direct object "*una carta*" and the indirect object "*a mi abuela*". If we are already talking about your grandma, you can say "*le escribí una carta*", where "*le*" replaces "*a mi abuela*".

Then you can replace the verb with "*cortar*" and the direct object with "*el pelo*" to get "*corté el pelo a mi abuela*" or "*le corté el pelo*".

You can do the same exercise with "*me duele la cabeza*" canonicalizing it into "*la cabeza duele a mi*" (but never use this form!), where "*la cabeza*" is the subject, and "*a mi*" is the indirect object that can be replaced by "*me*".

So there's no need for a possessive form at all to understand whose head we are talking about.

As a matter of fact, the first time a Spanish speaker learns that you need to use a possessive form in English to refer to body parts it sounds awkward and it takes some time getting used to it.